# Make large image responsive?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I am making website for desktop and mobile users using wordpress theme that I am editing (editing CSS). My problem is that front image is large and when user with low resolution (i.e. on mobile phone) connect on website, image is resized and only one tiny part is displayed. Here is screenshots that explain my problem:

Here is normal website visited by desktop user:

[image: Desktop user]

And here shrinked website when user with small resolution connect on website (i.e. with mobile phone)

[image: User on mobile phone]

As you can see, image now looks bad. Is there anyway to shrink image when resolution is low that whole image fits in that screen?

Here is CSS that I am using to display this picture:
This is container for DIV and some paragraphs

```
* =Featured Content
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#featured {
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
}

#featured p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #8B0000;
padding-top:250px;
padding-left:50px;
  text-align: left;
width:100%
}
#featured p1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 27px;
  font-style:italic;
  color: #8B0000;
padding-top:50px;
padding-left:50px;
  text-align: left;
width:100%;

}

#featured-image {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#featured-image .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.featured-image img {
  margin-top: 44px;
}
```

here is class for image:

```
    .col-940new {
  width: 100%;
  height:460px;
  background: url('uploads/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
}
```

and here is HTML that is used for this elements

```
<div id="featured" class="grid col-940new">
        <div class="grid col-460">

            <h1 class="featured-title">
                            </h1>

            <h2 class="featured-subtitle">
                            </h2>

            <p>


            </p>



        </div><!-- end of .col-460 -->

        <div id="featured-image" class="grid col-460 fit">



        </div><!-- end of #featured-image --> 

    </div><!-- end of #featured -->
```

**EDIT** :

After applying some methods commented bellow i manged to fix problem but now there is a "white space" that I want to remove when user connect to website on mobile phone.

Code is same except this line is added:

```
  background-size: 100% auto;
```

[image: User view from mobile phone]

Comment: Use background-size: contain;

Comment: @C-Link I tried but problem is that there is alot of "white space" that is not used....

Comment: try this background-size: 100% auto;

Comment: @C-Link Now it's okay but there is still "white space" on mobile resolution. I think that problem is in height:460px; . Will try to someting different and post results back.

Comment: @C-Link Since I am using specified value for height I think that there will be always "white space" for mobile users....

Answer (score 0):

As it is a background image, add this to your CSS

DEMO **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/BYZzq/)**

```
.col-940new {
  width: 100%;
  height:460px;
  background-image:url('uploads/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this code @Vector is that there is alot of "white space". Image doesn't cover whole space which results with blank space at corners of the image.

Comment: That's because a landscape image is used

Comment: as @C-Link suggested, I used background-size: 100% auto; and that worked very well

Comment: You could create a cropping situation where you crop the background image at a certain size and then position it so the preferred section is visible DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/BYZzq/1/

Answer (score 0):

> **If both components of background-size are specified and are not auto:**
>       The background image renders at the specified size.
>
> **If the background-size is contain or cover:**
>       The image is rendered, preserving its intrinsic proportion, at the largest size contained within, or covering, the background positioning area.  If the image has no intrinsic proportion, then it is rendered at the size of the background positioning area.
>
> **If the background-size is auto or auto auto:** If the image has both intrinsic dimensions, it is rendered at that size.  If it has no intrinsic dimensions and no intrinsic proportion, it is rendered at the size of the background positioning area.  If it has no dimensions but has a proportion, it's rendered as if contain had been specified instead.  If the image has one intrinsic dimension and a proportion, it's rendered at the size determined by that one dimension and the proportion.  If the image has one intrinsic dimension but no proportion, it's rendered using the intrinsic dimension and the corresponding dimension of the background positioning area.
>
> **If the background-size has one auto component and one non-auto component:**
>       If the image has an intrinsic proportion, then render it using the specified dimension, and compute the other dimension from the specified dimension and the intrinsic proportion.  If the image has no intrinsic proportion, use the specified dimension for that dimension.  For the other dimension, use the image's corresponding intrinsic dimension if there is one.  If there is no such intrinsic dimension, use the corresponding dimension of the background positioning area.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

In your case you have both width and height has intrinsic value so try to add `background-size: 100% 100%;` which might work for mobile device also. But your image is stretched, so if you don't want to be stretched your image just add cover at last like this magic happen:

```
background-size: 100% cover;
```

Comment: You could also try `auto 100%; ` coz you have defined height but width is 100% so auto.